# How to use Tailwind CSS together with SCSS in Laravel/Vue project?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, sass, tailwind-css

I'm trying to install `tailwind css` from [this guide](https://vuejsexamples.com/laravel-8-vue-3-and-tailwindcss-starter/) into an existing `laravel/vue` project, which uses `scss`.

1. install packages

   ```
   yarn add -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
   ```
2. create `tailwind.config.js`

   ```
   npx tailwindcss init
   ```
3. add tailwind to `webpack.mix.js`

   ```
   const mix = require('laravel-mix');
   const path = require('path');

   mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
       .postCss("resources/css/app.css", "public/css", [require("tailwindcss")])
       .alias({'@': 'resources/'})
       .webpackConfig({resolve: {alias: {'@': path.resolve('resources/')}}})
       .vue()
       .version()
       .browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');
   ```
4. add tailwind to `css`. Where do I add it, if my `scss filewatcher` is compiling the `css` files of my project? I've tried to put:

   ```
   @tailwind base;
   @tailwind components;
   @tailwind utilities;
   ```

or

```
@import tailwindcss/base;
@import tailwindcss/components;
@import taildindcss/utilities;
```

into `app.scss` but tailwind classes do not affect Vue components. I've also tried importing it into `app.vue` which did not work either. The tailwind classes are correctly displayed in the editor dialogue and browser DOM but the `css` props don't get rendered.

**Edit:**

I've added this to **`tailwindcss.config.js`** but the `css` still does not get rendered in the browser:

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
        './resources/views/*.blade.php',
        './resources/js/*.js',
        './resources/vue/**/*.vue',
        './resources/vue/*.vue',
    ],
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Does `content` of your `tailwind.config.js` file included vue files like `content: [ './resources/views/**/*.blade.php', './resources/js/**/*.js', './resources/js/**/*.vue',],` ?

Comment: It wasn't included but now I added it (edit section). Unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it because you don't have `vue()` method in your `webpack.mix.js` (at least I cannot see it in your question)? See [here](https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/vue)

Comment: @IharAliakseyenka `vue` is defined in `webpack`

Answer (score 0):

In your resources/css/app.css,
Add below code (Do not add to app.scss.)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

And add below code to your welcome.blade.php

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```